# Running SQL Server 2012 Express Scalar Function in View

Tags: sql, function, view, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2012-express

My SQL guru is in Costa Rica for the week and have a problem I don't know how to solve. I have four simple tables and one function. For simplicity sake I'll remove any fields not required to understand what I need.

Table1:

```
PRIMARY_ITEM_ID,
INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
```

Table2:

```
Table2ID,
INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
Table3ID
```

Table3:

```
Table3ID,
Department,
DepartmentJobType
```

Table4:

```
PRIMARY_ITEM_ID
DISCRETE_JOB
```

The function returns the `JobType` of the Job with Table4's `DISCRETE_JOB` column.

What I need: see all `INVENTORY_ITEM_ID`'s from `Table1`. Only show the department when JobType from table3 is equal to the result from my function.

The links are something like..

```
    Table1.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID -> Table2.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID 
AND Table1.PRIMARY_ITEM_ID = Table4.PRIMARY_ITEM_ID
    Table2.Table3ID -> Table3.Table3ID ONLY WHEN 
    Table3.DepartmentJobType = (SELECT FROM GetJobType_F(Table4.DISCRETE_JOB)
```

I'm hoping I can do this with what I have and not need to redesign my tables. (I do realize that if I had JobType in the Table1 I wouldn't need this but I would like to avoid changing the tables as much as possible. Any help would be awesome! Thanks other gurus!

Comment: I just thought that a CTE query appending the JobType to Table1 would probably work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue using a CTE query.